# Car jerks when low on fuel during acceleration and turning but then runs ok

Tags: fuel-system, bmw

I found a weird problem with my BMW E90. Recently when the fuel was low the car jerks when accelerating from start position and when the car is running it runs fine. Also yesterday while at the roundabout the car stopped while turning.

The jerky motion come in pulses and when turning on roundabout it doesnt even accelerate (only when low on fuel)
Could this be due to some block in the fuel system? But that doesnt explain nominal running after it has picked up speed.

Comment: At first blush, it sounds like the pickup sock on the fuel pump has come loose. Secondly, if this only happens when the fuel is low, don't let the fuel run low. Easy fix.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 are you pertaining to HPFP or in-tank fuel pump? Yes offcourse, I keep the gas full or atleast half empty from now on :)

Comment: On the in-tank fuel pump.

Comment: Gas keeps the pump running cool. It's always a good idea to keep the tank at least half full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PAULSTER2 mentioned, it was in-tank fuel pump issue. Replaced it and the car runs fine now. Although I didnt see any pickup sock on the fuel pump, but the old fuel pump had gone too brown in color, maybe someone might have put mud in my gas tank while I was travelling as the issue started after I returned from vacation.